# empty $_POST while sending Blob

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest, blob

I'm sending binary data to server using Blob, but there is nothing in `$_POST` variable. What did I do wrong?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/save.php', true);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("data", new Blob(["㚂☇䰉耸ڀ찃怮...binary...:⡒㠯ݟᑣ"]));
xhr.send(formData);
xhr.onload = function(e){
    if (this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
```

server side:

```
var_dump($_POST); //returns array(0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple fix...

When you send a `BLOB` it sends as a `file` not as `post` data. Therefore you need to use `$_FILES` not `$_POST`.

Using your code modified to `var_dump($_FILES)` outputs:

```
"array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "blob"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/tmpfilename"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(44)
  }
}
```

You could then open the file serverside with `file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmpname'])` same as you would any other uploaded file.

Comment: I was checked `var_dump($_FILES)` it was `NULL`

Comment: Even if it is empty it should return `array{}` if it returns `NULL` then it could mean that you spelt it wrong (unlikely but possible!) OR that your server has file uploads turned off. What's the output from `echo 'file_uploads: ', ini_get('file_uploads');`

Comment: `file_uploads: 1` is the result

Comment: What server are you running on? Is this VPS? A local test server?

Comment: Server:Apache/2.2, X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze17

Comment: Can you access the `php.ini` file? What's the output from `echo 'upload_max_filesize: ', ini_get('upload_max_filesize');` and `echo 'max_file_uploads: ', ini_get('max_file_uploads')`

Comment: that values are 200M, 20

Comment: Try using a standard form `<input typ="file" name="file">` to upload a file and make sure to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `form` tag and then `var_dump($_FILES)` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I managed to send that data this way:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/save.php', true);
xhr.send("㚂☇䰉耸ڀ찃怮...binary...:⡒㠯ݟᑣ");
xhr.onload = function(e){
    if (this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
```

server side:

```
var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); //string(1820) "㚂☇䰉耸ڀ찃怮...binary...:⡒㠯ݟᑣ"
```